# JPEG2000 encoder/decoder on Android

Tags: android, jpeg2000

I want to encode/decode jpeg2000 format on Android. Do you have any suggestions/tutorials to on how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Among other Google search results:

- https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jpeg+2000+encoding+java+library
- https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jpeg+2000+encoding+java+library+android&oq=jpeg+2000+encoding+java+library+android
- [Encoding image into Jpeg2000 using Distributed Computing like Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301065/encoding-image-into-jpeg2000-using-distributed-computing-like-hadoop)
- http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg2000guide/software/software.html